# Struggling with return data from a jQuery call to vb.Net asmx web service

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, web-services, asmx

I am writing my first HTML5 based app, I am also writing my first web service and attempting inner connectivity between the two.  Too facilitate a test bed for this I have setup a simple local `.vb` based web service which is as follows:

```
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Public Class Verify
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

<WebMethod()> _
Public Function HelloWorld() As String
    Return "Hello World"
End Function

<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Function UsernameVerify(ByVal username As String) _
    As Boolean
    Return (username = "Username")
End Function

<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Function PasswordVerify(ByVal pass As String) _
    As Boolean
    Return (pass = "RandomPassword123")
 End Function
End Class
```

I wanted to test that my app was able to connect to the web service, send the data, and receive the appropriate return.  To do this I used jQuery:

```
function verifyInfo(){
        $.ajax(  
        {  
            Type: 'Post',  
            url: 'http://localhost/TestWebService/Verify.asmx/HelloWorld',   
            success: function(data){alert(data);},
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                debugger;
            }
        });            
    }
```

The problem right now is that the value stored in data is printed as `[object Document]` and I am not entirely sure where to proceed from here.  From the call to HelloWorld function invoke I would expect to return a string `Hello World`. When I do a browser based test via debugging in visual studio the invokes work fine and return appropriate XML outputs such as:

`<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Hello World</string>`

Sorry for such a long post but hoping to get some guidance on how to get the expected data back as a return after POSTing to the web service.

Thank you in advance for any tips/hints/suggestions.

Comment: I have a feeling part of the issue is my webservices POST `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`  could this be part of whats causing my issue as well since it isn't a json object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASMX returns results in "d" wrapper. See this very nice article http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/

so try something like:

```
success: function(data){alert(data.d);}
```

UPDATE: Also try to define proper content type of your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: [your url]
    data: [your data],
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {alert(data.d);}
});
```

UPDATE 2: Try to also change your web method to this (add a response format):

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Function HelloWorld() As String
    Return "Hello World"
End Function
```

Comment: I followed those instructions ivan.sivak but the issue continues.  See my comment on the OP.

Comment: Once I add `data:{}, contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', dataType: 'json',` the alerts (success and error) do not fire.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response ivan.sivak I was out of town for the weekend.  Your second update did the trick and as suspected the problem all along was the fact that it wasn't returning JSON from the the web function.  Thank you very much for this.

Comment: I'd like to point out - for the people from the future - that if you omit the data field then webmethods will fail. I just figured that out as I had a one such method that didn't take any parameters so I naturally assumed I didn't need data in my ajax. I was wrong. It also appears that bool return values aren't liked either.